# how to scroll screen automatically in MVC App?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing MVC3 application and using razor syntax.

In this application I am giving comment facility.

The user supposed to fill the form or read the form as well user can put comments 
on that form/information.

Its look like this...

[image]

(Red line shows comment box and Blue line shows end of screen.)

Now the issue is, when user clicks on the comment button , the comment box is get opend but user can see only half of that box, so user have to scroll to see complete.

So, I want to write some code so when user click on that 'Comments' link, screen should scrolll automaticlly till that comment box view.

How to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Please use `window.location = "#writeYourCommentBox"` and `$("#writeYourCommentBox").focus()`

See this website to more info and examples http://www.ezineasp.net/post/Javascript-Location-Hash-with-Example.aspx

Comment: I am trying to use your mentioned code.where should I suppose to write that code ? in Jscript ?

Comment: @user1668543 yes it is classic javascript

Comment: focus only show a part of element on page if its down the visible screen or having part on visible screen and in case of :user1668543 comment box having part on visible screen

Comment: this is the reason to use windows.location, this will put the scroll onto the comment box

Answer (score 0):

yo can play with scroll top property after clicking  on comment link this will allow comment box to show on front you can also go with top property

Comment: Thanks, but Scroll Top property of what ?

Comment: its used for approch to give perticular location to an element with effect Animation